# Rails file_field_tag not uploading file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

I have a form:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => "foo", :action => "boo", :multipart => true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag "foo[bar]" %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit it, the `param foo[bar]` gives `"foo[bar]"=>"filename.png"` instead of an `ActionDispatch` object.

Anybody have any clues what might be the cause here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Solved. Needed to change the form_tag line to:

```
<%= form_tag ({:controller => "foo", :action => "boo"}), :enctype =>"multipart/form-data" do %>
    <%= file_field_tag "foo[bar]" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Or 
`multipart: true`

Comment: Note that with `form_for`, the `multipart: true` should be nested like so: `form_for(something, html: { multipart: true })`.

Comment: with form_tag, just use `<%= form_tag xxx_path, multipart: true do %>`